# Processing cannot create AVD

Tags: android, processing

I am trying to run a Processing sketch on Android emulator.  I get the following error-

```
debug:
Unhappy inside exists()
D:\android-sdks\tools\android.bat list avds
status: 1
375ms
stdout:

stderr:

D:\android-sdks\tools\android.bat create avd -n Processing-0215 -t android-10 -c 64M -s WVGA800
status: 1
308ms
stdout:

stderr:

at bottom of ensure proper
```

I tried running android.bat separately and that won't run either. But AVD Manager runs fine. I can create, run and delete emulators using AVD Manager.
Is it a problem with Android SDK installation or Processing?
How do i fix this?
Operating System: Windows 7 (64-bit)
Processing: 2.0b7
Android SDK: API level 10

EDIT:

Running android.bat gives me this-

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
    Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
    We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
   http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

I'm perplexed by the fact that AVD Manager runs but android.bat doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new AVD?

Comment: @EvZ Yes I tried creating a new AVD just as the parameters suggested. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Try to reduce the screen size and RAM.